# How to echo this value into html upon successful login Php

Tags: php, session, session-state

```
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <div class="left">
        <!--info-->

        </div>


    <?php

        if(!$_SESSION['id']):

        ?>

        <div class="left">
            <!-- Login Form -->
            <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                <h2>Login</h2>

            <?php

                    if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
                    {
                        echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                        unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
                    }
                ?>

                <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="User" size="23" onFocus="clearText(this)" />
                <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="Pass" size="23" onFocus="clearText(this)" />
                <label><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
            <div class="clear"></div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="left right">            
            <!-- Register Form -->

            <form action="" method="post">
                <h2>Sign Up!</h2>       
            <?php echo $id; ?>
            <?php

                    if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'])
                    {
                        echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'].'</div>';
                        unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']);
                    }

                    if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'])
                    {
                        echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
                        echo $_SESSION['id'];
                        unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
                    }
                ?>
```

I basically want to output the version of the `$_SESSION['id'];` into html upon submission so that it can be grabbed from the page as a user navigates the site. So, if a user were to go to `index2.php` and *logged in successfully*, their `ID` (the PK for their username and pass combo) would be outputted to HTML so the code could grab that if say they go to prof.php next, that session var ID from `$_SESSION['id'];` could be grabbed by the page and used on `prof.php` if a user were to submit the form on prof.php

Can someone please help me be able to reuse this ID over and over as pages are navigated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want the `id` variable to be accessible across all of the pages a user visits.

That is exactly what session is designed to do. You don't want to be writing the value to the page, since unless you put it in a form, and resubmit the form, the server side will never receive it again.

Check out this [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Basically on prof.php, you can access the $_SESSION['id'] variable.

Comment: how do I keep it going though? like on index.php their logged in fine then if i go to prof.php or dept.php, it loses the session and doesnt recognize the user is logged in. Why doesnt it work to put `<?php session_start(); ?>` in the beginning of every file?

Comment: Can you please show an example??? I have `session_start` at the top. Do I just access by doing `<?php $_SESSION['id']; ?>` below `session_start();` ?